# How to access python dictionary from C?

Tags: python, c, dictionary, struct, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a dictionary in python and I need to access that dictionary from a C program? 
or for example, convert this dictionary into struct map in C

I don't have any idea how this could be done.

I will be happy to get some hints regarding that or if there are any libraries that could help.

Update:

the dictionary is generated from the abstract syntax tree of C program by using pycparser. 
so, I wrote a python function to generate this dictionary and I can dump it using pickle or save it as a text file.

Now I want to use keys and their values from a c program and I don't know how to access that dictionary.

Comment: Are you running your python code in an interpreter embedded in an existing C program? Are you invoking compiled C code (a library; .dll/.so) from your python program? Are you wanting to invoke a totally separate process?

Comment: Is the dictionary a data structure within your python program, or is it a disk file that you access from your python program?  If it's a disk file, we need to understand what format it is in, so we can figure out the best way to access it from a C program.  If it is solely a data structure within your python program, we first need to figure out how to export it from your python program (probably as a data file in some format), after which we can figure out how to access it from a C program.

Comment: @SteveSummit I have updated my post with more details

Comment: Thanks @TomDalton please have a look I have updated my post

Answer (score 1):

You could export the dictionary to a JSON and parse the JSON file from C...